# How to access Windows 7 PC in Samba network?

Tags: 12.10, networking, windows-7, samba

First of all, sorry for my bad English, as it isn't my primary language.

I have a home network with my Ubuntu box, a Windows XP box (sister's laptop) and a Windows 7 box (mother's PC). Never had a mixed network; with some effort I could install Samba and see the PCs (and be seen for them).

All Windows PCs can access Ubuntu, create and delete files and folders in the shared folders like a charm, and I can do the same with the Windows XP PC. From Ubuntu to Windows 7, however, I can't; a window requesting credentials appears, but there's nothing password-protected accounts in Windows 7. There's just one user account on that computer, without password.

How can I access this computer?

Comment: What Windows 7 are you using?
Remember that Windows Starter Edition does not allow sharing!

Comment: Hopefully isn't WSE. It's a Windows Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the Windows 7 computer without a password?

---

I suggest you disable "Password protected sharing" on the Windows 7 computer, and then specially allow Guest account to access the shared components.

---

## To turn off Password Protected Sharing:

1. Click Start, enter "Network and Sharing Center" in the Start Search box .
2. Click "Change advanced sharing settings" in the left pane.
3. Make sure that "Password protected sharing" is turned off.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You might need to check that "Turn off password protected sharing" is selected under Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Network and Sharing Center.

You may also be able to give access to a Guest account on the Windows 7 box for the folders you want to share, and then from Ubuntu just enter the log-in name as *Guest*.

Comment: I have connected to Windows on password-protected share... Are you sure this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you to add a simple password in you Windows 7 system, a simple one just for you access the network in that case you can ask the system, both Ubuntu and XP, to memorize the password. I had the same problem; it's work very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a user on the Windows 7 machine for the username on the Ubuntu machine. For example, if you want to connect to the Windows machine as "Fred" you need to add a "Fred" user to the Windows machine to assign permissions in Windows 7.

Comment: It's exactly what I do not want to do. I access the other Windows (XP) computer without having to create an user especifically to this; must have a way to do this with Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 has very different security features than XP.

Comment: And yet uses the same network infrastructure. Besides, turning off password protected sharing resolved my question. Thank you to share your time, sincerely.